# Stream result from a SELECT to run multiple UPDATES concurrently

Tags: javascript, mysql

Using the `mysqljs` node module, I am updating a query that does an `UPDATE` on a big table in MySQL (more than 2 million rows) to avoid locking the table. So instead, I want to do a massive `SELECT` and iterate through the result rows to update them individually. I don't mind the updates being concurrent.

Here's what I tried :

```js
const oneHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
const pool = mysql.createPool({ 
        connectionLimit: 10, 
        host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
        user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
        password: process.env.MYSQL_PASS,
        database: process.env.MYSQL_DB
});

const rowHandler = (row) => {
    pool.query(`
        UPDATE member m SET
            received_today = (
                SELECT COUNT(id)
                FROM receives r
                WHERE r.member_id = m.id
                AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), r.action_date) <= 1
            ),
            clicked_today = (
                SELECT COUNT(id)
                FROM clicks c
                WHERE c.member_id = m.id
                AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), r.action_date) <= 1
            )
        WHERE m.id = ?
    `, row.id).on('error', errorHandler);
};

pool.query({sql: 'SELECT id FROM member', timeout: oneHour})
    .on('error', errorHandler)
    .on('result', rowHandler);
```

I get a bunch of `ECONNRESET` errors :

```
Error: write ECONNRESET
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:154:25)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:780:11)
    at Socket._write (net.js:792:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:454:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:436:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:327:11)
    at Protocol.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:85:26)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Protocol._emitPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:305:8)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at Pool.query (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:202:8)
    at Query.rowHandler (/app/index.js:17:7)  <----- This is the line where I do pool.query() in rowHandler()
    at Query.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Query.RowDataPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:158:10)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:260:14)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'write',
  fatal: true
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Not sure why you've tagged this with `php`.  Looks like node.js, right?

Comment: Yes it is but if there is a solution in PHP that allows concurrent updates it will be accepted

Comment: Tag removed though for the sake of simplicity